# Creating a multipage layout on MS-Word from scratch?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to create a document, or template, on MS-Word which will allow me to type content into 3x5 inch spaces on the page, flowing the text between these 3x5 spaces - similar to what Word does with its label creation tool, but without a mail-merge component.  In the printing trade this would be called ["page imposition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposition) but I found no help for that in MS-Word.

I've been completely unable to find any help for this in the help documents or online  - Everything seems to point back to "here's how you do a mail merge," which is NOT what I want to do.   I just want to create the underlying formatted document, and type in my own text.    I was wondering if someone either knew how to do this or could point me to the super-secret help online that can show me the way.

Comment: What you probably need is to look up "linked text boxes", create the 3x5in spaces you need, and link them. But I don't think you will be able to create a document that is "extensible" in the sense that you can add a new page and it's "linked in" the way you want. So perhaps a better approach would be to create one that has the maximum number of pages/boxes that you are likely to need, then create the document you want and remove any trailing pages that you do not need.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good plan.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: suggest that you will end up finding out the details (precisely how to do it and what does and does not work) so probably better if you post the answer when you are ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be exactly the right thing to do.   Size the text boxes to whatever space you want (in my case, the size of 3x5 index cards) and "link" them using the "Create link" tool (under Drawing Tools/Format).   Here's the answer from "bibadia":

`What you probably need is to look up "linked text boxes", create the 3x5in spaces you need, and link them. But I don't think you will be able to create a document that is "extensible" in the sense that you can add a new page and it's "linked in" the way you want. So perhaps a better approach would be to create one that has the maximum number of pages/boxes that you are likely to need, then create the document you want and remove any trailing pages that you do not need. – bibadia Dec 27 '15 at 20:27`